# IPv6: "Destination unreachable: No route" Routing error?

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

I've got an IPv6 address added to a bridge (sysctl has been configured to enable forwarding). However whenever I try to ping an IPv6 host it fails with the following error:

```
PING google.com(we-in-x65.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
From 2a00:dd0:0:28:216:3eff:fe1a:b34a icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: No route
```

This is my /etc/network/interfaces (Debian) config:

```
iface xenbr0 inet6 static
        address 2a00:0dd0:0000:0028:0000:0000:0000:0001
        netmask 64
        gateway 2a00:0dd0:0000:0028:0000:0000:0000:0000
```

This is the routing table:

```
root@nl:~# route -6 | grep dd0
2a00:dd0:0:28::/64             ::                         U    256 0     1 xenbr0
::/0                           2a00:dd0:0:28::            UG   1024 0     0 xenbr0
2a00:dd0:0:28::/128            ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
2a00:dd0:0:28::1/128           ::                         Un   0   1     7 lo
```

I got this from my ISP as my "IPv6 block": `2a00:dd0:0:28::1/64`. No other info was given.

Wondering if this is a router issue on their end or one on mine?

Comment: You should request more info from your provider... Also, are you sure that this is your subnet? usually, you get a /48 assigned, and the /64 is just for the routing between you and the provider.

Comment: @MichelZ I requested information but i'm still waiting to hear back. Yeah in my IP pools `2a00:dd0:0:28::1/64` is the only thing listed, I requested a /64 so I imagine this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2a00:dd0:0:28::1/64` is probably your default gateway since a block can't end with `1`.  Your host ip is set to the address of your default gateway and your default route points to your entire block `2a00:dd0:0:28::`.

Use a subnet calculator to figure out the range of addresses in your block and change your host IP.  Then see if you can ping `2a00:dd0:0:28::1`. If so try using it as a default gateway and then try to ping another internet host.  If these settings don't work contact your provider.

Also I haven't tried any google v6 addresses, but if you haven't successfully pinged them from another host try from a working host to make sure they answer.

Comment: Seems like you're right, that is the gateway. I'm now getting stuck at one of their routers in a traceroute so I assume it's no longer a problem in my server.

Comment: They could be blocking traceroute or tunneling through a network that doesn't support it.  Is any of your traffic getting to the internet (web, dns, etc.)?  If not I'd open a ticket with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the gateway from your ISP. Either **their router** is 2a00:dd0:0:28::1, or they expect you to have an additional IP on some other block of space that they route to 2a00:dd0:0:28::0/64 via.